# Creating models for household_objects_database

Tags: ros, household-objects-database, object-recognition

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm trying to add a new model in a local version of the household_object_database so I can recognize my own objects with the tabletop_object_detector.

I made a model in Solidworks and exported it to STL format, which I exported again to PLY format using Blender. Then I deleted all models from my local database and used insert_model.cpp to add my own model and added it manually to a model set, the database seems fine now. The problem is, when I launch tabletop_complete.launch I get the following error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'  
what(): std::bad_alloc
```

Everything works when I use the original models from the database, so I suspect that the model I made is faulty. Is there a better way to create models?  I also tried 3DSom as described in the link below, but 3DSom is licensed and doesn't work properly for me. Are there any other ways to create 3D models? Thanks in advance!

http://www.ros.org/wiki/household%20objects

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12520/creating-models-for-household_objects_database/) by [Hououin Kyouma](https://answers.ros.org/users/1579/hououin-kyouma/) on ROS Answers with karma: 205 on 2012-01-03

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My teammate solved the problem today, it appears that the household_database uses models specified in meters, while the model I had was specified in centimeters. Specifying the size in meters solves the problem.

As for ways to create 3D models, it doesn't matter what application you use, as long as it is able to export the model to PLY format. I used models created in 3DSom, Solidworks and 3dSMax and converted them to PLY format with Blender, which worked perfectly for me.

---

Originally posted by [Hououin Kyouma](https://answers.ros.org/users/1579/hououin-kyouma/) with karma: 205 on 2012-01-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2012-01-17**:
Hey could i have your email id, i mean i am not sure on how to use the tabletop_object_detector with household_object_database?

**Comment by [Hououin Kyouma](https://answers.ros.org/users/1579/hououin-kyouma/) on 2012-01-17**:
I used the latest version of the household_object_database, but I removed all objects in it for my own use.

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2012-01-17**:
Hey which version of the households backup file have used.